# Validating textbox only if checkbox is checked - no post back

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a asp.net CheckBox and I have a textbox, I only want textbox to validate when checkbox is checked otherwise just leave it like this.

I find MVC post but I want for asp.net forms [Validating textbox only if checkbox is checked using MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974502/validating-textbox-only-if-checkbox-is-checked-using-mvc)

This is my current code which validates textbox regardless of checkbox is checked or not,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjectRequired" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject" ErrorMessage="You must enter a subject." runat="server" />
```

Comment: please share your validation code also.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar it's a asp.net required validator, it doesn't have any other code :S

Comment: I believe, you just don't need Required Field Validator here, rather just validate through javascript on page submit using OnclientClick event. It will avoid postback also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a [custom validator](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/) ,then:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ControlToValidate="txtSubject" OnServerValidate="IsTextboxValid" Text="Text box is invalid" runat="server"/>
```

In code behind,define custom validation method:

```
protected void IsTextboxValid(object sender,ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid=chkSubjectRequired.Checked;

}
```

**Please note that this is Server-side Validation**

Answer (score 0):

[this is what you looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400346/disable-asp-net-validators-with-javascript) Just enable/disable the validator (also textbox if you want) that's all.

Answer (score -1):

Validate The Text Box Only Number :

```
   <input type="text" onkeydown="ValidateNumber(event);">

    <script>
    function ValidateNumber(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode >= 8 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
        return true
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: @NicoHaase i am not getting your question, plz explain

Comment: The OP asked about some validation that should only take place if a checkbox is checked, and your code does not take that into account

Comment: If checkbox is checked than this validation should work.. isn’t it..?

Comment: And how does your code check for the status of the checkbox, so how does it skip the validation if the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: if(document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked) { Above Code}

Comment: Please do not add code to the comment section. If that should be a part of your answer, edit the answer